# How to add sourcemap in React Native for Production?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, source-maps

I received error log like the following while the app crashed:

> Fatal Exception: com.facebook.react.modules.core.JavascriptException:
>   onSelect index.android.bundle:20:7148 onPress
>   index.android.bundle:20:2435

But it's not really helpful for me to trouble shoot. How could I enable source map so that I could track down where the issue is ?

**UPDATE 2018**
https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/using-sentry.html Looks promising !

Answer (score 62, accepted):

For source mapping here is the way I go about it:

In my bundle command for my production build I tell it to generate a source map:

iOS:

```
react-native bundle --platform ios --entry-file index.ios.js --dev false --bundle-output ./ios/main.jsbundle --assets-dest ./ios --sourcemap-output ./sourcemap.js
```

Android - I had to actually modify the android/app/react.gradle file to get source maps generating on release compile. There might be an easier way but basically you find where it builds up the bundle command in the bundleReleaseJsAndAssets method and add the source map bit to it:

```
if (Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS)) {
    commandLine "cmd","/c", "react-native", "bundle", "--platform", "android", "--dev", "false", "--entry-file",
        entryFile, "--bundle-output", jsBundleFileRelease, "--assets-dest", resourcesDirRelease, "--sourcemap-output", file("$buildDir/../../../sourcemap.js")
} else {
    commandLine "react-native", "bundle", "--platform", "android", "--dev", "false", "--entry-file",
        entryFile, "--bundle-output", jsBundleFileRelease, "--assets-dest", resourcesDirRelease, "--sourcemap-output", file("$buildDir/../../../sourcemap.js")
}
```

The output path looks a bit odd but that puts it at your root level (same spot as iOS. I wanted it that way. You can obviously put it anywhere).

Then once you have an error with the line number that means nothing you run it through the "source-map" NPM package. You could probably get very elaborate with your approach but I simply went with:

```
var sourceMap = require('source-map');
var fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile('./sourcemap.js', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
    var smc = new sourceMap.SourceMapConsumer(data);

    console.log(smc.originalPositionFor({
        line: 16,
        column: 29356
    }));
});
```

Where line and column should be replaced withe line and column number from your example output above.

This obviously works best if you have the source maps stored somewhere as the line and column numbers change from build to build as your code changes. It should get pretty close though if you can use you source control setup of choice to go back to the commit that was used to build the app in question and re-generate the bundle with the additional bits to the command to generate the source map.

Comment: I ended up got something similar to this and was looking for remote logging server that can do the source map automatically. https://docs.getsentry.com/hosted/clients/javascript/integrations/react-native/ looks interesting. but didnt manage to get it to work.

Comment: Ah, that would be interesting. I am just using Crashlytics to log the errors then manually mapping it with the above method when investigating the error. It would be nice to have a service that did it automatically but I have yet to see one.

Comment: I'd love to see this too, and for some reason I don't expect to see support for this added to Crashlytics anytime soon. Someone should build this!

Comment: On v0.24 worked for me: `commandLine "node", "node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js", "bundle", "--platform", "android", "--dev", "${devEnabled}", "--entry-file", entryFile, "--bundle-output", jsBundleFile, "--assets-dest", resourcesDir, "--sourcemap-output", "${bundleAssetName}.map"`
Also, You need to use local react.gradle. Issue: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/7393

Comment: On v0.32 it's simpler to add the args to generate a sourcemap. Just add    ```project.ext.react = [
 
  extraPackagerArgs: [ "--sourcemap-output", file("$buildDir/../../sourcemaps/sourcemap.js")]
]
``` to `android/app/build.gradle` just before the `apply from:` line.

Comment: My outputted sourcemaps returns the wrong values. It misses with some 10-20 lines when I produce an error! Any experiece with this? @chetstone

Comment: Here a slightly more convenient script. Cut&paste from the log file, and it should create the call stack: https://gist.github.com/shadowbrush/347e0a1fbda4fa38f15064d8602ffa80

Comment: Extending @chetstone answer, you can keep the sourceMap you created for each version of the app by using this `extraPackagerArgs:  ["--sourcemap-output", file("$buildDir/../../sourcemaps/sourcemap-${android.defaultConfig.versionName}.js")]` and moving the `project.ext.react` definition and the `apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"` line after the `android {...}` definition.

Comment: please anyone tell me where is write **fs.readFile('./sourcemap.js'...** code

Comment: just in case it helps anyone https://github.com/bugsnag/bugsnag-sourcemaps

Comment: `new sourceMap.SourceMapConsumer(data)` returns a promise, can you update your answer to reflect that? Perhaps this is a new change I don't know. This snippet works well otherwise

Answer (score 25):

**Android** inspired by @chetstone's answer

Starting on v0.32 for android, you can modify your android/app/build.gradle to accomplish this.
Look for the line

`apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"`

Just above this, you will see something like:

```
project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js",
]
```

Modify it to match the following

```
project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js",
    extraPackagerArgs: ["--sourcemap-output", file("$buildDir/../../../sourcemap.android.js")]
]
```

**On iOS**

Go to your build phases in Xcode for the "Bundle React Native code and images" phase and add:

```
export EXTRA_PACKAGER_ARGS="--sourcemap-output sourcemap.ios.js"
```

Comment: sourcemap file did not created form me. Can there be any reason for that.

Comment: I get these errors on Android: `FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Failed to capture fingerprint of input files for task ':cntral:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' property '$1' during up-to-date check.
> Failed to create MD5 hash for file '/Users/me/tmp/skylight-87084.sock' as it does not exist.`

Comment: I created an Issue on `react-native` for it since I can't seem to find anybody else with the issue: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/24044

Answer (score 4):

As noted, there's no obvious way to generate the `sourcemap` file for React Native on iOS. The `bundle` command is called from `react-native-xcode.sh`, and there's no provision to add parameters to the `bundle` command line. But I found a clean way to do it.

`react-native-xcode.sh` uses the environment variable `BUNDLE_CONFIG` to specify a config file. If you create an empty config file it has no effect, and then you can add additional CLI parameters.

Create an empty config file.

`touch null_config`

Set `BUNDLE_CONFIG` with your config file, and piggyback the `--sourcemap-output` parameter.

`export BUNDLE_CONFIG="null_config --sourcemap-output ./sourcemap.js.map"`

When you build, the file `sourcemap.js.map` will be created.

Comment: can you provide more details on this? where do you place the null_config file? what are it's contents exactly? do you set the env vars in Xcode?

Answer (score 4):

This is only for iOS.

step 1:  Generate sourcemap.js file by using following command.

add this line in package.json file

```
 "bundle:ios": "mkdir -p ios/{Bundle,source-map}; react-native bundle --platform ios --entry-file index.js --dev false --bundle-output ios/Bundle/main.jsbundle --assets-dest ios/Bundle --sourcemap-output ios/source-map/sourcemap.js"
```

Run this command, it will create sourcemap.js file under `$PROJECT_DIR/ios/source-map/` folder

```
$ yarn bundle:ios
```

Step 2: Create a file sourcemap-decoder.js under `$PROJECT_DIR/ios/source-map/`

```
$ cd ios/source-map/

$ touch sourcemap-decoder.js
```

Content of sourcemap-decoder.js is

```
const sourceMap = require('source-map'); //(install- npm i source-map)
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

fs.readFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'sourcemap.js'), 'utf8', async (err, data) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log('err', err,);
  }
  const consumer = await new sourceMap.SourceMapConsumer(JSON.parse(data));

  console.log(consumer.originalPositionFor({
    line: 1408,
    column: 7762
  }));
});
```

Step 3: execute the script for decoding

```
$ node ios/source-map/sourcemap-decoder.js
```