# Where to add source map command in Xcode for my production build when adding sourcemap for React Native for Production?

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

RE (don't have enough experience points to reply there): 
"In my bundle command for my production build I tell it to generate a source map"
[How to add sourcemap in React Native for Production?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34715106/how-to-added-sourcemap-in-react-native-for-production/34733906#34733906)

In Xcode Version 7.3 beta 3, I went to [My Project] > Build Phases > Bundle React Native code and images

Under:
export NODE_BINARY=node
../node_modules/react-native/packager/react-native-xcode.sh

I added:
cd /Users/andresn/dev/[My Project]
react-native bundle --platform ios --entry-file index.ios.js --dev false --bundle-output ./ios/main.jsbundle --assets-dest ./ios --sourcemap-output ./sourcemap.js

Is something like this what he meant, or is there a more proper way of doing this?

Comment: Note: you need a semicolon or line break after that first cd:
cd /Users/andresn/dev/[My Project];
react-native bundle --platform ios --entry-file index.ios.js --dev false --bundle-output ./ios/main.jsbundle --assets-dest ./ios --sourcemap-output ./sourcemap.js

Comment: Hey @Andres Narvaez did you manage to get this to work for you?

Comment: @brien.crean yeah, no problems to date after my last comment.

Answer (score 3):

A generic solution based on what you've already said:

```
export NODE_BINARY=node

if [ "${CONFIGURATION}" = "Release" ]
then
  cd "${PROJECT_DIR}/../"
  react-native bundle --platform ios --entry-file index.ios.js --dev false --bundle-output ./ios/main.jsbundle --assets-dest ./ios --sourcemap-output ./ios/main.jsbundle.map
else
  ../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react-native-xcode.sh
fi
```

Be sure to add the assets and main.jsbundle.map to your iOS project then create your release build again.

Comment: I really need to drag all assets to "Copy Bundle Resources"? How does react native do it automatically?

Comment: Created this: https://gist.github.com/brunolemos/ed81562c90fd4ce6682b6dcf338548ac

Answer (score 3):

I ended up using the following script in **Bundle React Native code and images**:

```
export NODE_BINARY=node
if [ "${CONFIGURATION}" = "Release" ]
then ../sourcemap.sh
else ../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react-native-xcode.sh
fi
```

Then in the project directory's root, I'm using the following **sourcemap.sh** script which generates a source map file in the **./ios** directory:

```
#!/bin/bash
$NODE_BINARY ../node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js bundle --platform ios --entry-file ./index.ios.js --dev false --bundle-output ./main.jsbundle --assets-dest ./ --sourcemap-output ./main.jsbundle.map
```