# How find out what is triggering a crash?

Tags: android, react-native, google-play

In Google Play Console > Crash Reports, I see that there are a few users that get this crash.
I get that somewhere there is an undefined variable and I am trying to access it's 'id' property. I can't reproduce this crash on the testing devices.

Looking in index.android.bundle I can see that there 30 'e.id' occurrences, some that come from my code, some from other react-native modules.
How can I find where is the issue?

Any tools I can use for this?

The app is build with "react-native": "0.53.3"

```
com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'e.id'), stack:
value@870:1304
onPress@870:3393
touchableHandlePress@170:1510
_performSideEffectsForTransition@163:8488
_receiveSignal@163:7275
touchableHandleResponderRelease@163:4740
y@41:1204
invokeGuardedCallback@41:467
invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError@41:582
H@41:2563
D@41:3325
F@41:3122
Ie@41:14792
<unknown>@41:15350
batchedUpdates@41:60665
_e@41:14565
ze@41:15336
receiveTouches@41:15879
value@18:3582
<unknown>@18:1067
value@18:3009
value@18:1039
at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ExceptionsManagerModule.showOrThrowError(ExceptionsManagerModule.java
  at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ExceptionsManagerModule.reportFatalException (ExceptionsManagerModule.java:40)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke (JavaMethodWrapper.java:374)
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke (JavaModuleWrapper.java:162)
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run (Native Method)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:739)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage (MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:31)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:148)
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$3.run (MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:194)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: The numbers beside your error represent the sourcemap row and column. With those numbers and your sourcemap in hand, you can deduce which line of code is exactly causing the crash. You can read more about sourcemaps here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34715106/how-to-add-sourcemap-in-react-native-for-production?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa