# Does crashlytics support react-native applications in production

Tags: react-native, crashlytics, crashlytics-android

Does fabric crashlytics supports react native application with release apks.
i have added fabric crashlytics to my app but the errors are not showing original file name where the error occured.After doing some research i found that we have to generate source map while bundling.But i didn't find any working example on how to generate source map for android and ios.

Comment: can you tell me how to generate source map for android

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34715106/how-to-add-sourcemap-in-react-native-for-production check here