# How to explore NSBundle contents?

Tags: ios, react-native, nsbundle

I've got NSBundle file named main.jsbundle packaged by react-native bundle, which tool I can use to explore it's contents? I can see that it got the minified js code inside, and also some sort of index at the beginning of file. I need to extract the js code in order to debug an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @ivanmoskalev pointed out, this might not be necceserily NSBundle. Anyway, piping the file through `strings` outputs pretty much just the javascript part of the file, so that works for me.

Answer (score 0):

`NSBundle` is a totally different thing – it is a native class representing an Apple format of packaging applications and frameworks, allowing to access and manipulate it from native code.

You are asking about a *React Native bundle*, which is quite a loose concept of a single file of minified JS code + an assets folder for images and data. You can actually de-minify the js-bundle using conventional tools such as [uglify-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uglify-js) and try to inspect it.

You can also use [sourcemaps produced by Metro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34715106/how-to-add-sourcemap-in-react-native-for-production), and maybe [metro-symbolicate](https://github.com/facebook/metro/tree/master/packages/metro-symbolicate/src) to understand how the minified code from the bundle maps to actual sources, although I can't recommend anything more specific without knowing the problem at hand. There is also no documentation for `metro-symbolicate`, meaning you'll have to grok its sources.

Comment: it is a bit different from a browser js bundle, because there's a bunch of binary data at the beginning of the file. I found that piping the file thru `strings` does the trick of stripping that binary data for me

Comment: Are you using RAM bundles then?

Comment: I think I actually do yeah, I remember setting up something like that.