# How to get error source file from firebase crashlytics stack trace text index.android.bundle or iOS main.jsbundle?

Tags: react-native, crashlytics, stacktrace.js

How to get the source file line and column information from a crashlytics stack trace line pointing to index.android.bundle:474:6500?

A crashlytics report stack trace text looks similar to:

```
Non-fatal Exception: io.invertase.firebase.crashlytics.UnhandledPromiseRejection: undefined is not an object (evaluating 't.includes')
       at .removeFile(index.android.bundle:474:6500)
       at .<unknown>(index.android.bundle:758:3472)
       at .y(index.android.bundle:105:596)
       at .<unknown>(index.android.bundle:105:2546)
       at .y(index.android.bundle:105:596)
       at .o(index.android.bundle:105:1483)
       at .<unknown>(index.android.bundle:105:1626)
       at .f(index.android.bundle:101:155)
       at .<unknown>(index.android.bundle:101:1012)
       at .y(index.android.bundle:107:657)
       at .C(index.android.bundle:107:1021)
       at .callImmediates(index.android.bundle:107:3216)
       at .callImmediates([native code]:0:0)
       at .value(index.android.bundle:25:3080)
       at .<unknown>(index.android.bundle:25:1264)
       at .value(index.android.bundle:25:2772)
       at .value(index.android.bundle:25:1234)
       at .value([native code]:0:0)
       at .value([native code]:0:0)
```

I tried stack-beautifier with limited success. Is there a more reliable method?

Answer (score 6):

I spent days trying to figure out a good solution.  This is the best I have found so far.

### 1) Build Source Maps from Git Tag or Commit Hash Corresponding to Version from Crashlytics Report

iOS

```
react-native bundle --platform ios --entry-file index.js --dev false --reset-cache --bundle-output /tmp/bundle.ios.js --assets-dest /tmp/ --sourcemap-output sourcemap.ios.js.map
```

Android builds automatically from build gradle

```
// https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/7393
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34715106/how-to-add-sourcemap-in-react-native-for-production/34733906
project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js",
    enableHermes: false,  // clean and rebuild if changing    
    extraPackagerArgs: ["--sourcemap-output", 
    file("$buildDir/../../../sourcemap.android.js.map")]
]
```

Or manually build:

```
react-native bundle --platform android --entry-file index.js --dev false --reset-cache --bundle-output /tmp/bundle.android.js --assets-dest /tmp/ --sourcemap-output sourcemap.android.js.map
```

### 2) Usage metro-symbolicate

1. Open crash report in your [Google Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/)
2. Select **Stack Trace** tab
3. Select **TXT** tab and save text to file named mytrace.txt
4. Remove all stack trace lines starting with first line containing "**[native code]**" as the
   "**[native code]**" seems to cause problems
5. Results example: error originates at Utility.js:567

```
npx metro-symbolicate sourcemap.android.js < fs-27-stack-trace.txt                                                                 
Non-fatal Exception: io.invertase.firebase.crashlytics.UnhandledPromiseRejection: undefined is not an object (evaluating 't.includes')
       at .removeFile(/Users/eddie/Documents/projects/react-native/my-react-native-app/v1.6.1146/source/app/components/Utility.js:567:includes)
       at .<unknown>(/Users/eddie/Documents/projects/react-native/my-react-native-app/v1.6.1146/source/app/components/software-downloader/DownloadClient.js:237:oldVersion)
```

I hope this may help others.

Comment: my stack traces are bunch of hex. I use "obfuscator-io-metro-plugin".
maybe you may guide here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74450412/react-native-firebase-crashlytics-deobfuscation-issues. thanks