# React native firebase crashlytics deobfuscation issues

Tags: react-native, crashlytics, react-native-firebase

I am having the following 2 issues on android.

1. not all crashes are reported. out of 5 maybe 3, sometimes 2.
2. even the saved reports are not readable in case of android

for iOS: crash report is somehow readable(not 100%). at least I get function name everytime.

attaching both screenshots.

Android: sometimes I see "props" word. sometimes hex there as well
[image: Android stacktrace]

iOS:
[image: iOS stacktrace]

Firebase.json:
[image: firebase.json]

proguard-rules
[image: proguard-rules]

build.gradle
[image]

- For code obfuscation I am using this package: "obfuscator-io-metro-plugin"
- The line which is causing the crash is: this.props.SomeUndefinedFunctionCall()

Comment: Just to confirm, is the "obfuscator-io-metro-plugin" obfuscating your code and then  the Android app gets obfuscated with Proguard? If so, I think Crashlytics could be only deobfuscating the Android app but not all the way back to what the plugin did.

Comment: Exactly this is happening, once javascript obfuscation is disabled. crash reports are semi readable. not exact file name and line number but some readable stuff with reference to bundle file.

Comment: thanks for the reply, btw is it possible to get exact file name and line number instead of bundle file. for both android and ios build?