# How to build an Android sourcemap with React Native 0.69

Tags: react-native, instabug

I'm using Instabug for crash reports for my React Native project. I need to upload an Android sourcemap so the logs can be useful. I'm using React Native 0.69.1 and did my install via the react native docs.

Instabug says to run this command:

```
react-native bundle --platform android \ 
 --entry-file index.js \ 
 --dev false \ 
 --bundle-output ./android/index.android.bundle \ 
 --sourcemap-output ./android-sourcemap.json && 
 zip ./android-sourcemap.zip ./android-sourcemap.json
```

Note, I had to replace `react-native` with `npx`. Here's the result:

```
zsh: command not found: react-native
zsh: command not found: --entry-file
zsh: command not found: --dev
zsh: command not found: --bundle-output
zsh: command not found: --sourcemap-output
```

I tried some of things mentioned in [How to add sourcemap in React Native for Production?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34715106/how-to-add-sourcemap-in-react-native-for-production) but was not able get anything to work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Remove the ` \` parts from this code and remove the newlines. It works as expected then.

Comment: Ah, thanks @luke. Turns out I needed to add `npx` in front of the whole line for it tor run.